# How can I add the row to a datagrid in wpf application at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have got an error when i dynamically add values to the observable collection which is binded with the datagrid's ItemSource.

```
 _Items.Add(new GridViewItem() {Name="Test1",ID=1});
```

> ```
> Error:This type of CollectionView does not support
> ```

changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you simply have to add the Item to the Observable Collection. Your Threading Error seems that you try to add the item in a not ui thread. so you have to use a dispatcher

```
  public ObsrevableCollection<MyTestItem> MyCollection {get; set;}


  <DatagGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />


  public void Add()//is called from a not ui thread
  {
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>this.MyCollection.Add(new MyTestItem(){ID=1, Name="Test1"}));
  }
```

Comment: It's not reflect any content in the Grid.